# github push problem Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I got an error message like this:

```
Pushing to github.com:xxx/xxxx.git
ERROR: Permission to xxx/xxx.git denied to xxx.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And I don't know how to fix this issue

[image]?

Comment: well, did you make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists?

Comment: If you've cloned your project with ssh. then you need to add public key in your github account. If this don't help can you please share the steps you've followed .